# Java Find out mutual elements in two arrays

Tags: java, intersection, set-intersection

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. Assume I have two Array with object Point.

```
Point[] a1 = {/*something that is Point*/}
Point[] a2 = {/*something that is Point*/}
```

And what I want is get the mutual things in two arrays without using java.util.*

for example

```
Point[] a1 = {Point1, Point2, Point3}
Point[] a2 = {Point2, Point3}
```

I want to get an new array a3 that is

```
a3 = {Point2, Point3}
```

The things that confuse me is, I have no idea how long a3 will be.
So do I have to loop through both a1, a2 to count how many mutual items there,
and

```
Point[] a3 = new Point[count]
```

Then loop through the a1, a2 again and put items in?? This looks pretty inefficient. Are there more elegant ways to do it, as this may come up all the time.

Comment: You want to do the intersection? (That's a keyword, use it to search)

Comment: yup get the intersection without using java.util.*

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't use `java.util.*`?

Comment: That looks more interesting

Comment: Search for **List.retainAll**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because arrays are not re-sizable, what you can do is make an array that has a size equal to the size of the smallest of the two other arrays.

Keep an index for that array and add common elements as you loop through both arrays.

When you are done, create a new array with a size equal to the index you've reached and copy them over.

But, honestly, use `java.util.*` or some other library like `Guava`.

Comment: OK.. this saves one loop

Comment: @TimothyLeung Implement your own `linked list` :) to dynamically resize.

Comment: @TimothyLeung If you still need to return an array, not really, since you will still have to iterate over all the elements and copy them over to an array. You might save some memory.